# Symmetry of IP complexity class

Tags: interactive-proof-systems

Wikipedia defines the [IP complexity class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_(complexity)) as follows:

> A language $L$ belongs to IP if there exists $V,P$ such that for all
>   $Q$, $w$,
>   $$w\in L\Rightarrow Pr[V\leftrightarrow P\text{ accepts }w]\geq2/3$$
>   $$w\notin L\Rightarrow Pr[V\leftrightarrow Q\text{ accepts }w]\leq1/3$$

Note that this definition is asymmetric; it says (if we are polynomial-bound) we can be convinced $w\in L$, but says nothing about convincing us that $w\notin L$. We could define a class coIP containing the complements of languages in IP; that is

> A language $L$ belongs to coIP if there exists $V,P$ such that for all
>   $Q$, $w$,
>   $$w\notin L\Rightarrow Pr[V\leftrightarrow P\text{ accepts }w]\geq2/3$$
>   $$w\in L\Rightarrow Pr[V\leftrightarrow Q\text{ accepts }w]\leq1/3$$

It turns out IP=PSPACE and clearly PSPACE is symmetric under taking complement. Thus IP=coIP. Is there a direct way to see this? That is,

> Given a proof system $(V,P)$ for proving membership in $L$, can we use
>   it to construct a proof system $(V',P')$ for proving membership in
>   $\bar L$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no relativizing technique to show that $\mathrm{IP}$ is closed under complement.

Clearly, $\mathrm{NP}\subseteq\mathrm{IP}$.

Fortnow and Sipser gave an **oracle** relative to which $\mathrm{co}$-$\mathrm{NP}$ does *not* have *interactive proof system*.

So, you have to study the **arithmetization technique** that settles down this conjecture (long ago).

[Are there interactive protocols for CO-NP](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=D01796CED8897D984DEC0346462730D1?doi=10.1.1.42.111&rep=rep1&type=pdf)